Interpretation of a sigma-algebra not generated by a random variable.
I am wondering what is the interpretation of a sigma-algebra that is not generated by a random variable?
For example if we have a random variable $X$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$ then the sigma-algebra generated by $X$ is $\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(B): B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$. Then the interpratation is easy: If we observe what the value of $X$ is, we can know that an event in $\sigma(X)$ has happened or not. Because we know what the value of $X$ is, and then we know if $X\in B$.
However, lets say you have a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t))_{t \in [0,\infty)},P)$. Often we do not specify that the filtrations are generated by a stochastic process(but we may have a stochastic processes $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ adapted to this filtration, and we may have that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is strictly bigger than $\sigma\{\sigma(X_s): s\in [0,t] \}$). In this case, how does then the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_t$ "represent all the information up to time t"? Can we say that in this case that at time $t$ we know if the events in $\mathcal{F}_t$ has happened or not? Is this the correct interpretation for an abstract filtration? So at time $t$ I do not know the real $\omega$, but I know if $\omega\in F$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F}_t$?
I guess interpretations are not defined in mathematics. But is this the correct interpretation for abstract sigma-algebras not generated by measurable functions/random variables?

Maybe just think about discrete time? Like if you have a random walk $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ on $\mathbb{Z}$, then up to the $n$-th step there are $2^n$ many possibilities, which partition $\Omega$ into $2^n$ many events. These could be all of $\mathcal{F}_n$, or it may also contain more stuff.

Consider the family of indicators $\{\mathbf{1}_F,F\in \mathscr{F}_t\}$. Then $\cup_{F\in \mathscr{F}_t}\sigma(\mathbf{1}_F)=\mathscr{F}_t$. The inclusion $\cup_{F\in \mathscr{F}_t}\sigma(\mathbf{1}_F)\subseteq \mathscr{F}_t$ follows from the fact that each $\mathbf{1}_F$ is a $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable function. The other inclusion follows from the fact that if $E\in \mathscr{F}_t$ then $\sigma(\mathbf{1}_E)$ is contained in $\cup_{F\in \mathscr{F}_t}\sigma(\mathbf{1}_F)$ which implies $E \in \cup_{F\in \mathscr{F}_t}\sigma(\mathbf{1}_F)$. Therefore, you can always think about any $\mathscr{F}_t$ as being generated by $\mathscr{F}_t$-random variables, in particular by all the indicators of the events in $\mathscr{F}_t$.
